# Karma - Force failure on tslint warning for tests

Tags: angular, karma-runner, tslint

We currently have our `webpack` build command set up to fail if there are tslint warnings. This was done by using the following config:

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
        tslint: {
            emitErrors: true,
            failOnHint: true
        },
//...
```

This doesn't seem to cover our spec files which are built and exercised using Karma. When our tests are run using `karma start`, we see more tslint errors in all of our test code. Is there any way to force Karma to fail on any tslint warnings as well?

For reference, our `karma.conf.js` looks like:

```
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';

module.exports = function (config) {
    var _config = {

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',

        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [{
            pattern: './karma-shim.js',
            watched: false
        }],

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            './karma-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },

        webpack: webpackConfig,

        webpackMiddleware: {
            // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
            // i. e.
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },

        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true // please don't spam the console when running in karma!
        },

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'mocha'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ["mocha", "coverage", "junit"],

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: isTestWatch ? ['Chrome'] : ['PhantomJS'],

        browserNoActivityTimeout: 20000,

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: true,
        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'coverage/test-results.xml',
            useBrowserName: false
        },
        client: {
            captureConsole: true
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'coverage/',
            reporters: [
                {
                    type: 'html',
                    dir: 'coverage'
                }, {
                    type: 'lcovonly',
                    subdir: 'report-lcov'
                }, {
                    type: 'text-summary'
                }, {
                    type: 'cobertura',
                    subdir: '.',
                    file: 'cobertura.xml'
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    config.set(_config);

};
```

Comment: you looked at this yet https://github.com/yisraelx/karma-tslint

Comment: @AmanTuladhar that did not work for me. Seems to fail when the code has tslint failures but not when spec files have tslint failures.